# Filter and return multiple values from JSON nested List

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, typescript

I have a JSON file contains the name of the US state and cities-

```json
[
  {
    "state": "Iowa ",
    "id": "IA",
    "places": [
      {
        "city": "Ames",
        "description": "ames-description"
      },
      {
        "city": "Davenport ",
        "description": "davenport-description"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "state": "Illinois ",
    "id": "IL",
    "places": [
      {
        "city": "Chicago",
        "description": "chicago-description"
      },
      {
        "city": "Elgin ",
        "description": "elgin-description"
      },
      {
        "city": "Joliet ",
        "description": "joliet-description"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I would like to filter out the list by city name and return the description, corresponding state, and state id. Here is my code for the filtering the list-

```js
const cityname = Elgin;// 

//Filter array which matches the constant
const filterPosts = stateNames.map((filterPlaces) => {
  return filterPlaces.places.filter((getArray) => getArray.city === cityname);
});

//Get the name
const getCity = filterCity.map((topicCityArray) =>
  topicCityArray.map((getCityTitle) => {
    return getCityTitle.city;
  }),
);
```

My App.tsx

**Update:**
I want it to be dynamic. Here is my full CityPage.tsx file

```
const CityDetailsPage = () => {


    //Get city ID from URL
    const { cityname } = useParams() //let's say Elgin

    //Filter array which matches the constant
const filterPosts = stateNames.map((filterPlaces) => {
  return filterPlaces.places.filter((getArray) => getArray.city === cityname);
});

//Get the name
const getCity = filterCity.map((topicCityArray) =>
  topicCityArray.map((getCityTitle) => {
    return getCityTitle.city;
  }),
);

   



    return (
        <>
        
            <p>{getCity}</p>
           
        </>
    )
}

export default CityDetailsPage
```

It returns the city name. I could not figure out how to return the corresponding description, state name, and state id.
Say someone clicks the Elgin, this code will match the value from the list and return the following- Name of the city, state ID, Full name of the State, and the description of the city, something like-

```
Elgin, IL
Illinois
description of Elgin
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Technical note: either you have JSON, which is plain text string data, or you have "normal JS data" because you _parsed_ that JavaScript Object Notation string. In this case, you're not working with JSON, you're working with a normal JS array containing plain objects. That also changes what to search for: you want to filter _an array_, not JSON, and not a list (lists are a Python language feature).

Comment: It would help greatly if you could [edit] your question to include an example of the result you want. Also note that some of your `city` values have trailing spaces

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans OP says they have a JSON file

Comment: Indeed, which their code clearly doesn't work with, it works with the parsed JSON as plain data.

Comment: `const cityname = Elgin;` I take it `Elgin` is some other variable?

Comment: _"I am looking for something like"_... please provide concrete examples. Is that some sort of data structure or a formatted string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to produce a flat array from a nested result.

Combine this with `filter()` to reduce the flat list to the matching cities

```js
// Your data minified
const stateNames = [{"state":"Iowa ","id":"IA","places":[{"city":"Ames","description":"ames-description"},{"city":"Davenport ","description":"davenport-description"}]},{"state":"Illinois ","id":"IL","places":[{"city":"Chicago","description":"chicago-description"},{"city":"Elgin ","description":"elgin-description"},{"city":"Joliet ","description":"joliet-description"}]}];

// Create a flat map
const allPlaces = stateNames.flatMap(({ state, id, places }) =>
  places.map((place) => ({
    stateName: state,
    stateId: id,
    ...place,
  })),
);

// Filter by city
const cityname = 'Elgin';
const matches = allPlaces.filter(({ city }) => city.trim() === cityname);
console.log(matches);
```

This has the benefit of producing a single list that you can search multiple times for different matches (a reasonably common search usage).

---

In the context of a React app, you can use it like this

```jsx
import stateNames from './states.json'; // just guessing

const allPlaces = stateNames.flatMap(({ state, id, places }) =>
  places.map((place) => ({
    stateName: state,
    stateId: id,
    ...place,
  })),
);

const CityDetailsPage = () => {
  //Get city ID from URL
  const { cityname } = useParams();

  const cities = allPlaces.filter(({ city }) => city.trim() === cityname);

  return cities.map((place) => (
    <p>
      {place.city.trim()}, {place.stateId}<br />
      {place.stateName}<br />
      {place.description}
    </p>
  ));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job. If you don't feel compelled to use unnecessarily esoteric constructs. As a wise man once said: "Keep it simple, stupid".

```
const states = 
    [
        {
            "state": "Iowa ",
            "id": "IA",
            "places": [
                {
                    "city": "Ames",
                    "description": "ames-description"
                },
                {
                    "city": "Davenport ",
                    "description": "davenport-description"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "state": "Illinois ",
            "id": "IL",
            "places": [
                {
                    "city": "Chicago",
                    "description": "chicago-description"
                },
                {
                    "city": "Elgin ",
                    "description": "elgin-description"
                },
                {
                    "city": "Joliet ",
                    "description": "joliet-description"
                }
            ]
        }
    ];
// console.log(states);

const searchCity = 'Joliet';

let ret = [];

states.forEach(state => {
    // console.log(state);
    state.places.forEach(place => {
        if (place.city.includes(searchCity)) {
            // console.log(place.city);
            ret.push({
                city: place.city.trim(),
                description: place.description,
                state: state.state,
                id: state.id
            });
        }
    });
});

console.log(ret);
```

Comment: Upvoted. I was considering using the if-else as well. Your answer cleared up my confusion.